# Apply a function to each combination of columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame with `n` columns and want to apply a function to each *combination* of columns. This is very similar to how the `cor()` function takes a data frame as input and produces a correlation matrix as output, for example:

```
X <- data.frame(A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100), C=rnorm(100))
cor(X)
```

Which will generate this output:

```
> cor(X)
            A           B          C
A  1.00000000 -0.01199511 0.02337429
B -0.01199511  1.00000000 0.07918920
C  0.02337429  0.07918920 1.00000000
```

However, I have a custom function that I need to apply to each combination of columns. I am now using a solution that uses nested for loops, which works:

```
f <- function(x, y) sum((x+y)^2) # some placeholder function

out <- matrix(NA, ncol = ncol(X), nrow = ncol(X)) # pre-allocate
for(i in seq_along(X)) {
  for(j in seq_along(X)) {
    out[i, j] <- f(X[, i], X[, j]) # apply f() to each combination
  }
}
```

Which produces:

```
> out
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 422.4447 207.0833 211.4198
[2,] 207.0833 409.1242 218.2430
[3,] 211.4198 218.2430 397.5321
```

---

I am currently trying to transition into the tidyverse and would prefer to avoid using for loops. **Could someone show me a *tidy* solution for this situation?** Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could do

```
library(tidyverse)
f <- function(x, y) sum((x+y)^2)
X <- data.frame(A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100), C=rnorm(100))

as.list(X) %>%
  expand.grid(., .) %>%
  mutate(out = map2_dbl(Var1, Var2, f)) %>%
  as_tibble()
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn’t a `tidyverse` solution, but it does avoid using for loops. We use  `RcppAlgos` (I am the author) to generate all pair-wise permutations of columns and apply your custom function to each of these. After that, we coerce to a matrix.

```
set.seed(42)
X <- data.frame(A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100), C=rnorm(100))
library(RcppAlgos)

matrix(permuteGeneral(ncol(X), 2, repetition = TRUE, FUN = function(y) {
    sum((X[,y[1]] + X[,y[2]])^2)
}), ncol = ncol(X))
#          [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
# [1,] 429.8549 194.4271 179.4449
# [2,] 194.4271 326.8032 197.2585
# [3,] 179.4449 197.2585 409.6313
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R you could do:

```
set.seed(42)
X <- data.frame(A=rnorm(100), B=rnorm(100), C=rnorm(100))

OUT = diag(colSums((X+X)^2))
OUT[lower.tri(OUT)] = combn(X, 2, function(x) sum(do.call('+', x)^2)) #combn(X,2,function(x)sum(rowSums(x)^2))
OUT[upper.tri(OUT)] = OUT[lower.tri(OUT)]
OUT
         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]
[1,] 429.8549 194.4271 179.4449
[2,] 194.4271 326.8032 197.2585
[3,] 179.4449 197.2585 409.6313
```